# Frontend Javascript Nodejs

Tags: javascript, html

I want to send inputs from the frontend to the backend using JavaScript and HTML as Frontend and NodeJS, and MySQL as the backend I want to put validation for email and other fields in the frontend. I am using the post data function for sending the data and also the Validate Email function for the email validation. I cannot insert the data into the backend how can I do this?

```
function myfunction(){
        let firstName = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        let lastName = document.getElementById("lname").value;
        let email = document.getElementById("email").value;

        let address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        let phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
        let fees = document.getElementById("feespaid").value;
            function postData() {
            function ValidateEmail(email) {
             if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(email)) {
                 return (email)
             }
             alert("You have entered an invalid email address!")
             return (false)
         }
```

my HTML code is below

```
<b><label for="fname">First name:</label><br></b>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
    <b><label for="lname">Last name:</label><br></b>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
    <b><label for="email">Email:</label><br></b>
    <input type="text" id="email"style="width:200px;" name="email"><br><br>
    <b><label for="address">Address:</label><br></b>
    <input type="text" id="address"style="width:400px;height:50px;" name="address"><br><br>
    <b><label for="phonenumber">Phonenumber:</label><br></b>
    <input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phonenumber"><br><br>
    <b><label for="Feespaid">Feespaid:</label><br></b>
    <input type="number" id="feespaid" name="feespaid"><br><br>
   <button type="button" onclick="myfunction();">submit</button>
    
<button type="button" onclick="getStudentsData()">view</button>
<button type="button" onclick="download()">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write validation like this and use to validate before sending request to api.
Data variable contains information that is to be checked. Data has two properties email and password which is taken from frontend and passed to validate

```
const validator = require("validator");
const registrationvalidation = (data) => {
  let errors = {};
  if (data.username) {
    if (!validator.isLength(data.username.trim(), { min: 6, max: 30 }))
      errors.username = "Username must me 6 and 30 charater";
  } else {
    errors.username = "Username is required";
  }
  if (data.password) {
    if (!validator.isLength(data.password.trim(), { min: 6, max: 30 })) {
      errors.password = "password must me 6 and 30 charater";
    }
  } else {
    errors.password = "Password is required";
  }
  return {
    errors,
    isValid: Object.keys(errors).length == 0,
  };
};
module.exports = {
  registrationvalidation,
};
```

Comment: how can I use for email